# JSON transfer not working between processes

Tags: python, json

I am creating a board game, and long story short: I want a file that will start up and set the main variables of the game (player name, board(array), prompt, status - playing/gameover) and export these as a .json file. The set up file is a large GIU file so I would like to run the main game (logic and display) in a separate file.

I am practising doing this with a simple tic-tac-toe game, but for some reason I cannot get the json file to export/import correctly (can't really tell which) OR can't get an input function to work in the separate function.

(code is very basic and still incomplete, but I am simply trying to get the first step to work - start up, ask for name, then run the file with a function that will display the board and ask for the users next move)

solution 1) using subprocess.Popen

file1:

```
import json, subprocess, os
from distlib.compat import raw_input


print('Welcome to TIC-TAC-TOE!')
print()

#Set up of the start information that is going to be passed as JSON payload and sent to each process back and forth
#------------------------------------------------
name = raw_input('Please enter your name: ')
prompt = 'select a space: '
board = [0,1,2,
     3,4,5,
     6,7,8]
move = None
status = 'playing'
winner = None
iter = 0
#------------------------------------------------


#JSON payload {dictionary} to be sent
info = {'name':name, 'prompt':prompt, 'board':board, 'move':move, 'status': status, 'winner': winner, 'iter': iter, }

print('START, info dictionary as it goes out: ', info)



#file out which dumps info the info.json file
fout = open('info.json', 'w')
json.dump(info, fout)
fout.close


subprocess.Popen(["python3", "engineANDvisuals.py"])
```

file 2) 'engineANDvisuals.py'

```
#imported libraries
import random, funcs as f, json
from distlib.compat import raw_input



#front-end: iterface function
def interface(jsonFile):

   fin = open(jsonFile, 'r')                                                        #open up the     json file to read
   info = json.load(fin)                                                             #load json file as info
   fin.close                                                                        #close the json file

   print('FRONT, info dictionary as it comes IN: ', info)
   print()

   name = info['name']                                                                  #set json-name to name 
   prompt = info['prompt']                                                      #set json-prompt to prompt   
   board = info['board']                                                            #set json-board to board
   winner = info['winner']                                                          #set json-winner to winner
   status = info['status']                                                          #set json-status to status      


   f.printBoard(board)                                                              #prints out the board so that the user can see it
   print(info['move'])
   info['move'] = input(f.returnName(name)+', please '+ f.returnPrompt(prompt))

   print('FRONT, info dictionary as it goes OUT: ', info)

   fout = open(jsonFile, 'w')                                                       #open up the json file to write
   json.dump(info, fout)                                                            #dumps new info into the file   
   fout.close                                                                       #closes the json file
```

The f.functions are simple print functions located in another file. With this method I am getting all the way up to the input line in the second file, then the program just stops. It doesn't terminate, my cores aren't running hard at all (so I don't think it's in a loop) it just stops after the program asks for the space.

method 2) now if I use os.system instead to open up the process it gives me a huge error that I am taking to mean it is importing/exporting the json file incorrectly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "engineANDvisuals.py", line 105, in <module>
    interface('info.json')
  File "engineANDvisuals.py", line 19, in interface
    info = json.load(fin)                                                                #load json file as info
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am so insanely confused because when I run the second file alone after the first it works perfectly.

I would really appreciate some help, I know it's probably some silly overlook, a noob could really use some help, thank you so much.

Comment: `engineANDvisuals.py` only contains a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : `fout.close` is missing the parens - you want `fout.close()` - or better use a `with` statement:

```
with open('info.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(info, fout)
```

Longer answer:

Without the parens, `fout.close` evals to the `close` method of `fout`, but the method is not called:

```
>>> f = open("foo.txt", "w")
>>> print f.close
<built-in method close of file object at 0xf0d660>
```

Since the file is not closed, the buffer is not flushed to disk, so the subprocess cannot read it's content.

Once the main process ends, the file object is closed at garbage collection time and the buffer is flushed to disk, so if you execute the second script on it's own at this time it does read the file content.

Comment: great! Thank you so much, this works for the os.system way, silly overlook ah!         Do you have any idea why I would still be having issues with the subprocess.Popen one? It's not a huge deal now that I have the other working, but it still seems to get stuck on the input line, and was wondering if it was something specific to inputs on a separate process.

Comment: `subprocess` can be tricky indeed - but is there a reason to use subprocess at all here ?